# How to streaming decompress using boost iostreams

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, boost-iostreams

I'm using boost iostreams (1.64.0) in order to decompress zlib data.
I want to do streaming decompression. That means the compressed data are unpredictable size.
I wrote the following code example.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

int main() {
    // Compress
    std::stringstream sender;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
    out.push(sender);
    sender << "Hello World";
    std::stringstream compressed;
    boost::iostreams::copy(out, compressed);

    // Decompress
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(compressed);
    std::istream is(&in);
    std::size_t const buf_size = 256;
    char buf[buf_size] = { '\0' };
#if 0
    is.getline(buf, buf_size); // works fine
#else
    std::size_t read_size = is.readsome(buf, buf_size);
    std::cout << "read_size:" << read_size << std::endl;
#endif
    // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/
    std::cout << "rdstate:" << is.rdstate() << std::endl;
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;

}
```

I use `readsome()` because the size of data is unpredictable.
I got the following output:

```
read_size:0
rdstate:0
```

It was unexpected for me.

If I use `getline()` instead of `readsome()`, I got the following output:

```
rdstate:2
Hello World
```

It was expected output.

I think that when I use `readsome()`, the out put should be the same.
I can't use `getline()` my in actual code because the original data is binary format.

Is there any way to use `readsome()` with `filtering_streambuf` or any good way to streaming decompress unpredictable length binary data?

Comment: Why not use `read()` instead

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I realized that I misunderstood `istream::read()` and `istream::readsome()`  behave like as `boost asio`'s `read()` and `socket::read_some()`.

I replaced

        `std::size_t read_size = is.readsome(buf, buf_size);`
        `std::cout << "read_size:" << read_size << std::endl;`

with
        `is.read(buf, buf_size);`
        `std::size_t read_size = is.gcount();`
        `std::cout << "read_size:" << read_size << std::endl;`

then my code work as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [sehe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680590/how-to-streaming-decompress-using-boost-iostreams?noredirect=1#comment76379448_44680590), the problem is solved.

I wrote [the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680590/how-to-streaming-decompress-using-boost-iostreams?noredirect=1#comment76382562_44680590) for the comment but it is difficult to read because codes are not well formatted. So I answer by myself. I hope it will help for other people who have similar problem.

I replaced

```
std::size_t read_size = is.readsome(buf, buf_size);
```

with

```
is.read(buf, buf_size);
std::size_t read_size = is.gcount();
```

, then problem is solved.

I had misunderstood that `std::istream::read` blocks until reading `buf_size` length data. It is not true. Even if the actual read size is less than buf_size, the function returns. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/. In order to get `read_size`, I call `std::istream::gcount()`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/.

NOTE: I had gotten confused with [`boost::asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html) and [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::read_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html). But their behavior are different from `std::istream`'s one.

Here is the complete code of the fixed version:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

int main() {
    // Compress
    std::stringstream sender;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
    out.push(sender);
    sender << "Hello World";
    std::stringstream compressed;
    boost::iostreams::copy(out, compressed);

    // Decompress
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(compressed);
    std::istream is(&in);
    std::size_t const buf_size = 256;
    char buf[buf_size] = { '\0' };
    is.read(buf, buf_size);
    std::size_t read_size = is.gcount();
    std::cout << "read_size:" << read_size << std::endl;
    // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/
    std::cout << "rdstate:" << is.rdstate() << std::endl;
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;

}
```